# M2: Can't save customer because created_at date gets malformed by Magento

Tags: customer, magento-2.0.5

This is a followup to my previous question. Previously, I had an issue where the customer `created_at` attribute was incorrectly assigned a `datetime` input filter when it should have been `date`.

However, I still cannot save a customer because of the way Magento is parsing the date.

**vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Filter/Date.php**

```
public function inputFilter($value)
{
    $filterInput = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
        ['date_format' => $this->_dateFormat, 'locale' => $this->localeResolver->getLocale()]
    );
    $filterInternal = new \Zend_Filter_NormalizedToLocalized(
        ['date_format' => DateTime::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT, 'locale' => $this->localeResolver->getLocale()]
    );

    $value = $filterInput->filter($value);
    print_r($value) // 2013-07-18 04:00:00
                    // ^ Date is OK!
    $value = $filterInternal->filter($value);
    print_r($value) // 013,-07,-18, 04,:00,:00
                    // ^ Woah, what happened?!
    return $value;
}
```

So, why does `Zend_Filter_NormalizedToLocalized` completely destroy my date format and prevent me from saving Customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem short-term, I commented out the line:

```
 $value = $filterInternal->filter($value);
```

and faced no adverse effects.

Later, I discovered that going into the Admin and going to Customer Attributes, I could edit `created_at`, and turn off all validation which fixed the problem completely.